# Safe to store a tabletop vertically?

Tags: storage

I’ve made a 5/4” x 36” x92” maple tabletop for a family member.

They won’t be able to pick it up for a month, possibly more. Normally I store all my wood horizontally however this takes up too much room storing it for a long time flat.

Both sides are unfinished. It will be leaning on the inside of an outer garage wall. And there's not much air circulation.

Will I create problems if I store vertically instead of horizontally until they can pick it up?

Comment: How long are we talking about - a week? A month? A year?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. We need much more detail than you've provided to supply try to answer. First and foremost is what @MattDMo has asked about. While wood is stiffest along the grain, and there should be minimal tendency for a tabletop to bend under its own weight e.g. resting against a wall, there is potentially a *huge* difference between doing this for a week or two and a couple of months (or longer). And there are other highly relevant factors, including what the wall is, how much airflow and whether one or both sides are finished and if so with what.

Comment: Probably a month possibly more.  
Both sides Unfinished maple.  Inside of an outer garage wall. Not much air circulation.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details, they are just what we needed. You'd be surprised how often we don't get these after they're requested! I've edited them into the body of the Question as some people may not see them in the Comments.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your table top is glued-up long planks, with or without appropriately attached bread board ends. If that is the case, and it is actually vertical, or reasonably close to vertical, and you can store it so that you have equal air flow on both sides, you can store it that way indefinitely.    5/4" maple is plenty stiff, so it's not going to bend or warp from the storage position *per se,*  even with a little lean in it.   But if you store so that it breaths significantly differently on the two sides, then you are at real risk of trouble, as the boards that are not absolutely straight grain are likely to cup from differential moisture movement.

Answer (score 0):

Given the additional details then you do need to take some precautions to help ensure this doesn't warp.

There's little to no risk of your tabletop *bowing* under its own weight because 5/4 maple is plenty stiff, however you do have to concern yourself with *cupping*.

Just as a board or glued-up panel can cup just sitting flat on the workbench (or on the floor) due to differential drying, here, if you don't ensure even-ish airflow on both sides your tabletop could cup.... *in fact, if the wood was recently milled to final thickness this is **likely**.*

The side leaning against the wall, or just closer to the wall, can experience significantly less airflow and hence the side facing out can take up and loose much more water. Additionally as your top will be against a garage wall as I suspected it would be, a small pocket of higher humidity could result which would further increase the humidity differential between the two sides.

Thinner boards and panels — which respond faster than thicker material — can warp *overnight* from this effect, something that not a few woodworkers have found out the hard way. A month is more than enough time for this to occur even on something this thick.